# Both variables have same contents but show different hashcodes,same happens with Lists but it works with int,String and doubles

Tags: flutter, dart

```
    void main(){
    var x=Object(33);
    var y=Object(33);
    print(x.hashCode);    
    print(y.hashCode);
              }
    class Object{
    int a;
    Object(this.a);
                }
```

> Both have different hashcodes even if both are same instantiations

Comment: You´re welcome. If my post helped you out, I´d appreciate it if you could upvote and accept my answer :)

Comment: I would surely have but I am a beginner to this site,so I can't upvote yet, but I surely will once I am eligible :)

Comment: Thank you, accepting is always possible though (check mark next to the answer). This is important, so others can quickly see which answer was helpful and whether the question was answered yet :)

Comment: oh ok got it,checkmarked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy the code below into [dart pad](https://dartpad.dev/?) to check it on your own!

```
   void main() {  
  
    var x = MyObject(33); // Instance X
    var y = MyObject(33); // Instance Y
    var z = x;            // Instance X
    print(x.hashCode);  // hashCode: 329225559  
    print(y.hashCode);  // hashCode: 758565612
    print(z.hashCode);  // hashCode: 329225559
    bool result1 =  identical(x, y);
    bool result2 =  identical(x, z);
    print(result1); // false - They are NOT the same instance!
    print(result2); // true - They are the same instance!
  
   var a =  const MyConstantObject(33);
   var b =  const MyConstantObject(33);
   print(a.hashCode); // 479612920
   print(b.hashCode); // 479612920
   bool result3 =  identical(a, b);
   print(result3); // true - They are the same instance!

   var c = const MyConstantObject(33); // Creates a constant
   var d = MyConstantObject(33); // Does NOT create a constant
   print(c.hashCode); // 479612920
   print(d.hashCode); // 837581838
   bool result4 =  identical(c, d);
   print(result4);// false - NOT the same instance!
}
  
class MyObject{int a; MyObject(this.a);}
class MyConstantObject{ final int a ; const MyConstantObject(this.a);}
```

If you check out the flutter api for the [**hashCode property**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Object/hashCode.html) you can find out the following:

> The default hash code implemented by Object represents **only** the
> identity of the object, the same way as the default operator ==
> implementation only considers objects equal if they are identical (see
> identityHashCode).

In conclusion, yes both variables (or in my example all three) have the same "content", however, only x and z are **identical** as these variables hold the exact same instance.

If you dive deeper into the resource linked above (esp. in how the == operator works), you will find out why your approach works with int, String and double types (instead of your CustomObjects).

**Note - As you can learn [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#using-constructors), if you are constructing two identical compile-time constants, it results in a single, so-called canonical instance.** See example above with var a, b, c, d (adapted from the dart language tour).