# Documentation says "default operator == implementation only considers objects equal if they are identical",why isnt it applied here?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
    import 'dart:core';

    void main() {
    String characters = 'World';
    String a = 'Hello $characters';
    String b = 'Hello $characters';
    print(a == b);
```

> Outputs true for equality operator

```
    double x = 3.5;
    double y = 3.5;
    print(identical(x, y));
    print(identical(a, b));
```

> Outputs true in dartpad but false in VS code

```
    List eq3 = const [1, 2, 3];
    List eq4 = [1, 2, 3];
    print(eq3 == eq4);
    print(identical(eq3, eq4));
    }
```

Comment: If I test it on dart pad, both yield true.

Comment: Yes as I said ,but it outputs false on VS code :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Documentation says "default operator == implementation only considers objects equal if they are identical",why isnt it applied here?

You provide multiple cases, so it's not clear what specific expectations you have that differ from reality.

> ```dart
> String characters = 'World';
> String a = 'Hello $characters';
> String b = 'Hello $characters';
> print(a == b);
> ```
>
> Outputs true for equality operator

`a == b` is true because `String` does not use the *default* `operator ==` implementation.  [`String` provides it own override](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/String/operator_equals.html).

> ```dart
> double x = 3.5;
> double y = 3.5;
> print(identical(x, y));
> print(identical(a, b));
> ```
>
> Outputs true in dartpad but false in VS code

It's unclear what output you're observing.  `identical(x, y)` should be true in both environments: `x` and `y` are both initialized from the same `double` literal.

`identical(a, b)` returns true *when transpiled to JavaScript* as an implementation detail.  In that situation, Dart `String`s are backed by JavaScript strings, and [many JavaScript implementations do string interning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5276915/).

`identical(a, b)` *might* return `false` when run through the Dart VM because it can generate separate `String` objects.  But it also might return `true` if you compile a release-mode binary which performs more optimizations.

Ultimately whether `identical(a, b)` in your example returns true or not is an implementation detail that you should not rely on.

> ```dart
> List eq3 = const [1, 2, 3];
> List eq4 = [1, 2, 3];
> print(eq3 == eq4);
> print(identical(eq3, eq4));
> ```

You don't say what output you observe (nor what you expect).  In this case, `List` does *not* override the default `Object.operator ==`.  Therefore `==` and `identical` will behave, well, identically.  Both `==` and `identical` will return `false` because you necessarily have two different `List` objects.

Answer (score 1):

The == operator tests whether two objects are equivalent. Two strings are equivalent if they contain the same sequence of code units. See [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#strings).

Edit: You can look back at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70225621/15117201) regarding your third code snippet.

Comment: As a beginner,I don't understand last 4 lines :(

Comment: VS code adds imports (at the top of your dart files) automatically if you use a function, which requires an extra library/package, which is not covered by importing flutter´s material dart. This can lead to importing the "wrong" package, thus using the wrong identical() method. Read [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages).

Comment: Ok I tried importing dart:core but still it returns false

Comment: Can you post your entire dart file please?

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: Copy paste your dart code in VS Code and add it to your question by editing it

Comment: Ok I am adding it,its actually nothing much

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the `FileSystemEntity.identical` *method*.  It's asking about the `identical` *freestanding function*.

Comment: @jamesdlin Honestly, it is more about understanding the different outputs. That was the only method that returned a false boolean for me, but please feel free to share a different solution which produces a false in VS code, whilst returning true in dart pad ;)

Comment: @jamesdlin I agree with your answer, however, my answer was posted before OP edited it - so I had to look for another cause for returning false. But just comparing a and b in the first example did not yield false in my case with the freestanding indentical function.